# how to check if the printed value of a random.choice matches with a "guess" variable

Tags: python, windows, random

Basically, I'm writing a basic "hello world" code to refresh my memory and I'm stuck. I want to print a random choice from the list `numbers` and I want to check to see if my initial `x` matches with the output that was randomly chosen. However, when I run the code all I'm getting is `print("nice")` even when the numbers don't match. Here is the code:

```
import random

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = int(input("Enter your guess: "))

def random_choice(numbers):
    if x in numbers:
        print(random.choice(numbers))
        if numbers.count(x):
            print("nice")
        else:
            print("not nice")


random_choice(numbers)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `numbers.count(x)` will return the number of occurrences of `x` in numbers, since in that point of the code you already know that there is at least one copy of `x` in it (because this line is inside of the `if` that checks for `x in numbers`), it will always return a positive number which is implicit cast to `True`

A possible approach is to store the random value and compare to `x`:

```
import random

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = int(input("Enter your guess: "))

def random_choice(numbers):
    if x in numbers:
        temp = random.choice(numbers)
        print(temp)
        if temp == x:
            print("nice")
        else:
            print("not nice")


random_choice(numbers)
```

Comment: If this answers your question, please consider accepting.